# Appling a function in pandas with python

Tags: python, pandas, function

Looking for some guidance with pandas .apply function  See some code below:

Essentially I read in some data and want to calculate using business_duration library the business days between an open and close date of a ticket.

The issue is with the line:

```
df['x'] = df.apply(lambda x: businessDuration(startdate=df['Open_Date'], enddate=df['Close_Date'], starttime=biz_open_time, endtime=biz_close_time, holidaylist=US_holiday_list,unit=unit_hour), axis=1)
```

I'm trying to create a new column called it "x" and it's created by applying the function businessDuration where I pass it a open and close date along with necessary other parameters.  It makes me ponder that I'm not passing the data correctly.  I think I could pass each row of open and close date but that would not be efficient using pandas.

I get an error when running it stating that the truth value of a series is ambiguous.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeff

```
---
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlite3
from business_duration import businessDuration
import pandas as pd
import holidays as pyholidays
from datetime import time
######################################################################
# main()
######################################################################
def main():
   print("Connecting to databases...")
   cn_sndb = sqlite3.connect(r"E:\Database\sndb.sqlite")
   ######################################################################
   print("Importing Data...")
   ######################################################################
   q1 = """
       select RITM, Cat_Item, Request_Type, RITM_Stage, RITM_State, Open_Date, Close_Date
       from NewComputer
       where ritm_stage not like '%cancel%'
   """
   df = pd.read_sql(q1, cn_sndb)
   # #Start date must be in standard python datetime format
   # start_date = pd.to_datetime(df['Open_Date'][0])
   # #Start date must be in standard python datetime format
   # end_date = pd.to_datetime(df['Close_Date'][0])
   # #Business open hour must be in standard python time format-Hour,Min,Sec
   biz_open_time=time(7,0,0)
   # #Business close hour must be in standard python time format-Hour,Min,Sec
   biz_close_time=time(17,0,0)
   # #US public holidays
   US_holiday_list = pyholidays.US(state='VA')
   # print(US_holiday_list)
   # #Business duration can be 'day', 'hour', 'min', 'sec'
   unit_hour='day'
   # #Printing output
   # print(businessDuration(startdate=start_date,
   #    enddate=end_date,
   #    starttime=biz_open_time,
   #    endtime=biz_close_time,
   #    holidaylist=US_holiday_list,
   #    unit=unit_hour))
   
    df['x'] = df.apply(lambda x: businessDuration(startdate=df['Open_Date'], enddate=df['Close_Date'], starttime=biz_open_time, endtime=biz_close_time, holidaylist=US_holiday_list, 
        unit=unit_hour), axis=1)
   
    del df_incident
   
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main() (edited)
```

Comment: This is a good example of where if you provided a small sample set of data from your df, you could have provided everything we need to copy/paste your code and help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I dont think there is a need for you to use the lambda in this case, because the only thing you do is apply the `businessDuration` function. So try to remove the `lambda x:` I guess. You could also take a look at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applying-lambda-functions-to-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: Or if you do use the `lambda x:` then change any reference to `df[..]` to `x[..]`.  With what you have now you are doing a full vectorized operation on each row of the frame.